# How i can add ContextMenu in ListView (want to add "Modify" operation when someone do right click on ListView item ) in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I am trying to implement right click operation on ListView item and want to show some function on right click like "Modify".

```
                                              Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >
                                        <ListView.View>
                                            <GridView>
                                                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Book Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Book Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RSSI}"/>
                                            </GridView>
                                        </ListView.View>
                                    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a context menu in code-behind once the user click on the right mouse's button using **PreviewMouseRightButtonUp** event so :

- Create a name proprety for your ListView example: `<ListView  x:Name="test">`
- In your constructor initialize the event listner for your ListView after calling the **InitializeComponent** method like this :

  ```
  public your_constructor()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      /*
       Your codes here ...
       */
      test.PreviewMouseRightButtonUp += delegate
      {
          System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
          System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem modify_menu = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();
          modify_menu.Header = "Modify";
          modify_menu.Click += delegate
          {
              //your codes here once the user click on "Modify" ... 
          };
      };

  }
  ```

  **Happy Coding**

Comment: Thanks for the  prompt reply .  please let me know how i can send old price from XAML to code behind file . ( when someone press right click "modify" old price should send to code behind (Xaml.cs) file.

Comment: you can access to whole selected object using YourListViewName.SelectedItem